# How to send multipart files and form data together to Spring controller

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-3

In a form there are many text fields and four multpart file and I have to  send both together to the spring controller. Please sugget how it can be done in spring 3.x.

I am new to spring framework and did not find anyway. All the example I found is of Springboot not for the Spring 3.x

Answer (score 0):

For sending multipart files and form data together to spring controller you can use below code snippet :

In JSP :

```
<form method="POST" action="uploadMultipleFile" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    File1 to upload: <input type="file" name="file"><br /> 
    Name1: <input type="text" name="name"><br /> <br /> 
    File2 to upload: <input type="file" name="file"><br /> 
    Name2: <input type="text" name="name"><br /> <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload"> Press here to upload the file!
</form>
```

and in your controller you can receive data something like this :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadMultipleFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
String uploadMultipleFileHandler(@RequestParam("name") String[] names,
        @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile[] files) {

    if (files.length != names.length)
        return "Mandatory information missing";

    String message = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        MultipartFile file = files[i];
        String name = names[i];
        try {
            byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();

            // Creating the directory to store file
            String rootPath = System.getProperty("catalina.home");
            File dir = new File(rootPath + File.separator + "tmpFiles");
            if (!dir.exists())
                dir.mkdirs();

            // Create the file on server
            File serverFile = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath()
                    + File.separator + name);
            BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                    new FileOutputStream(serverFile));
            stream.write(bytes);
            stream.close();

            logger.info("Server File Location="
                    + serverFile.getAbsolutePath());

            message = message + "You successfully uploaded file=" + name
                    + "<br />";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "You failed to upload " + name + " => " + e.getMessage();
        }
    }
    return message;
}
```

You can go through this example : [file upload](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/spring-mvc-file-upload-example-single-multiple-files)

Another way to do this is something like this [click here](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-multi-file-upload-example/)

Comment: Thanks for helping hand. I will try with it. Meanwhile please guide how to manage the the file upload dynamicaaly.Let me explain, in form there are two sections, let's say Section-1 and Section-2. In both the Section there is a drop down list and two file uploads let's say 'Section-1-dropDownList-1' for section-2 it is 'Section-2-DropDown-2'. User will select the item from the drop down and do two file upload against the selected item.Similarly user will select item from drop down for section-2 as well and select the file for upload against the selected item.I am using angularjs and spring 3.x

Comment: @vimal I guess your form having two section and each section you have multiple files to upload based on section. For this you can create two list of multipart jsut make sure in UI you should have to assign same name attribute for each section multipart list.